# Python - no boolean display at the terminal

Tags: python, terminal, boolean

I am studying algorithms with Python and currently working on recursive and iterative binary search, I think the code is correct.

When I launch the program from the terminal I do not have any output.
It should return `True` twice, one from the *iterative function* and the other one from the *recursive function* but it doesn't display any boolean.

```
mbp-de-mathieu:programmation Mathieu$ cd python/
mbp-de-mathieu:python Mathieu$ python3.8 hello.py
coucou mathieu
mbp-de-mathieu:python Mathieu$ python3.8 binary_search.py
```

However I can get down in the console after the program call by using enter. Could someone explain to me what is happening? I am using a Mac.

```
data = [2,4,5,7,8,9,12,14,17,19,22,25,27,28,33,37]
target = 25

def linear_search(data, target):
    for i in range(len(data)):
        if data[i] == target:
            return True
    return False

def binary_search_iterative(data, target):
    low = 0
    high = len(data) - 1

    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if target == data[mid]:
            return True
        elif target < data[mid]:
            high = mid - 1
        else:
            high = mid + 1
    return False

def binary_search_recursive(data, target, low, high):
    if low > high:
        return False
    else:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        if target == data[mid]:
            return True
        elif target < data[mid]:
            return binary_search_recursive(data, target, low, mid-1)
        else:
            return binary_search_recursive(data, target, mid+1, high)

print(binary_search_iterative(data, target))
print(binary_search_recursive(data, target, 0, len(data)-1))
```

Thank you in advance

Wishing you a nice weekend

Best Regards

Mathieu

Comment: In `binary_search_iterative` your `high = mid + 1` should be `low = mid + 1`. (Your recursive function seems okay, but it is not started because the iterative function does not complete.)

Comment: Thank you very much @alaniwi